# using intent on android to show activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have two `activity` classes. I have a button on the first one and I want to show the second when it is clicked, but I get **force close** when  ever i run the application. Here are the classes:

```
public class APP extends Activity {

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button b1,b1a,b2,b2a,b3,b3a; 


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tts = new TextToSpeech (this, null);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
        b1.setOnLongClickListener(new Button.OnLongClickListener(){


            @Override
               public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                String hi = "Time";
                tts.speak(hi, 0, null);

                return false;
            }});

            b1a = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
            b1a.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0){
            {

                Intent i = new Intent(APP.this, Time.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
          }
       });
```

and to link it to :

```
public class Time extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.time);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                TextView txt_username = 
                    (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

                data.setData(Uri.parse(
                        txt_username.getText().toString()));

                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

There are no errors with the codes, it only force closes when the button is pressed.
I even added the *time class* to `manifest`, but the problem still persist. Is there anyway to solve this problem? thanks in advance. :D

---

this is my current manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="net.learn2develop.APP"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
            android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".APP"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity  android:name=".Time"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter> 
      </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

But, the problem still persist. it force closed after i press the button to link to time activity. and when i check up the `logcat`, it says:

```
07-13 14:25:56.384: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3799): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {net.learn2develop.APP/android.text.format.Time};
```

Have you declared this activity in your **AndroidManifest.xml?**

Comment: you have declared another activity in Time activity....public class Time extends Activity { public class Activity2 extends Activity { @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)...is this typo ? And can you copy stack trace from logcat and copy it over here. Thanks

Comment: Logcat please. I don't quite understand the code here.

Comment: please past your manifest.xml file and logcat file also

Comment: i'm new to android programming, so....what do i do to show u guys the logcat?

Comment: In DDMS View, there is a logcat table which shows the output of emulator(debug statements to Exceptions). So when exception occurs goto logcat and copy the exception.

Comment: this is my manifest.


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
       android:label="@string/app_name">
       <activity android:name=".Time" />
        <activity android:name=".APP"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            </application>
</manifest>

Comment: here's the logcat by part:

07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {net.learn2develop.APP/android.text.format.Time}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)

Comment: 07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at net.learn2develop.APP.APP$2.onClick(APP.java:70)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)

Comment: 07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-12 13:21:46.977: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25369):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 13:21:46.987: WARN/ActivityManager(174):   Force finishing activity net.learn2develop.APP/.APP

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your Time Activity 
You don't have any onCreateMethod on it.You declared onCreate on in inner class Activity2
But you wrote to start Time Activity from your App Activity.

If you write `Intent i = new Intent(APP.this, Time.class);`.It will look for Time Activity.But you didn't define Time Activity Correctly.Create onCreate method with appropriate syntax on the Timer Class Activity

Also check your manifest file whether you signed Time Activity or not

Comment: frm the above comment where i showed my manifest, i did indicate : <activity android:name=".Time" />

Comment: can u show me what u mean by "Creating a onCreate method with appropriate syntax on the Timer Class Activity" ?\

Comment: Now you got it right.It was wrong when you first posted the question.There was no onCreate method on your Time Activty

Comment: so....the current code is right? but when i run the app, it still force closes when the button is pressed.

Comment: sign time activity in manifest? isn't it this: <activity android:name=".Time" /> ?

Comment: <activity android:name=".App"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Time"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
         
                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: why is there a extra : <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not mentioned the classes in menifest you wanted to call ;Use these permission lines to call another activity

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:enabled="true" android:name="Time" />



</application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: i tried ur method, and added that code into my manifest. it still force closes when i press the button to link to time activity.

Comment: @ichiboo:-I wonder about the name of your class.Do you changed it to Time.java As it was an inner class while you started working

Comment: when i created it as a sub class, i named it Time.java
oh...and for those that know how to see the logcat, i've pasted mine at the top in the comments. ^^

Comment: @ichiboo check you have given id of button to the text (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

Comment: @avi Kumar Manku u mean in my time xml file?

Comment: no in java code of time you are referring textview with button id

Comment: in my Time java or APP java?  cause as far as the image button goes, it's in time application. and my time xml is :   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/clock">
    </ImageButton>

Comment: @Avi Kumar Manku: i don't really understand your qn. mind explaining?

Comment: btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                TextView txt_username = 
                    (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

                data.setData(Uri.parse(
                        txt_username.getText().toString()));

                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }     your refering your text of time xml in Time java file with button id, not with the text id

Comment: @Avi Kumar Manku: i've tried your method, seems right. but the result is still the same. it force closes when button is pressed.

Comment: The error might be somewher else because i tried your given code there is no crash might be something else, and you have referred both buttons in the APP activity with same id   (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_time);

Comment: @Avi Kumar Manku: hey, do you want to see my full code? i'll send u the project file so you can run it on eclipse to see how it looks like. then you might be able to find the problem.   ^^

Comment: @ ichiboo i am also new to android i might not help you much but i will give it a try,but an experienced person will help you better

Comment: @Avi Kumar Manku: it's ok. just give it a shot. do u have email? i'll send the attatched file to you. and i'll tell you the objective and the goals of my project in the email as well, so you'll have a clearer picture. ^^

Comment: hey avi, i've sent you the file. do read the description. hope you can solve the problem. thanks in advance. ^^